# How should I add a link at the bottom of the View in iPhone

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uitableview, uiwebview

I have a table view with 4 rows and at the bottom of the table view footer for the table I need to display an URL link. It should open the corresponding web page.

For example I need to have a link named "[Search using web](http://Search%20using%20web)" and this link should take the view to http://www.google.com. How can I implement this?

Comment: can you show your screenshot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly You add UITextView in each row of table view

```
textView.text = @"Search using web";
textView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeLink;
```

Open On The safari use this code....

```
NSURL *url = [ [ NSURL alloc ] initWithString: @"http://www.google.com" ];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:url];
[url release];
```

any Help use this [IOS Refernce](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1495/_index.html)

Answer (score 0):

Use label to display the "Search Using Web" text. You can also underline the text. And then on the touch event of the label write your code to open the link.

```
-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{   
    UITouch *touch= [touches anyObject];
    if ([touch view] == your_labelName)
    {
           write your code here to open the url..   
    }
}
```